# what happens on returning previous activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, return

when we go to another activity and come back via "finish();" or the back button of android, what happens?is the activity reloaded using the oncreate() method or resumes to previous state of the calling activity?

Comment: Have a look into Android life-cycle

Comment: go with this link  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activity A and Activity B,

When you move from Activity A to Activity B the lifecycle is as follows

```
Activity A
--------------------
onCreate()                    //A
onStart()                       //A 
onResume()                 //A - here user can interact with UI(buttons,views), user click button and it moves to second activity
onPause()                    //A
--------------------
onCreate()                    //Activity B
onStart()                       //B
onResume()                 //B

--------------------
onStop()                       //A - onStop() of Activity A is called after onResume() of Activity B

Now user presses back button in Activity B, then lifecycle as follows

onPause()                    //B
-------------------------------
onStart()                       //A 
onResume()                 //A

onStop()                      //B
onDestroy()                 //B
```

This is lifecycle flow between two activities

Answer (score 0):

`onResume()` method will be called when you get back to previous activity.